# LXC container network/routing issues

Tags: debian, networking, virtual-machine, container

I have been experimenting with LXC virtualisation in order to run virtual machines on a dedicated server, but am having trouble setting up the networking properly.

I am using veth bridged networking, as instructed here: http://blog.foaa.de/2010/05/lxc-on-debian-squeeze/ (the guide I used to setup the LXC container)

When I start the container, it functions fine, can access the Internet and accepts incoming connections to it's own IP. However, as soon as I start it, the networking on my host box (dedicated server) goes down completely, and will not come back until the server is rebooted.

The only thing I can think of that would be causing this is incorrectly configured bridging settings, however I'm not sure entirely what the proper ones should be. Any advice on how I could reconfigure this? Thanks.

Both the host node and the container itself are running Debian Squeeze, with packages upgraded to the latest versions.

Host node (dedicated server) network configuration (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
allow-hotplug eth0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 0 
    address 46.105.102.29
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 46.105.102.0
    broadcast 46.105.102.255
    gateway 46.105.102.254
```

LXC container network configuration (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 94.23.153.205
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 94.23.153.205
    post-up route add 46.105.102.254 dev eth0
    post-up route add default gw 46.105.102.254
    post-down route del 46.105.102.254 dev eth0
```

Container network configuration (from LXC config file):

```
lxc.utsname = paradox
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 02:00:00:ba:47:a0
lxc.network.ipv4 = 94.23.153.205
```

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: I'm not all that familiar with LXC. Regardless, I have a few observations that may be helpful, as I have quite a lot of experience with Debian networking, bridges, and VMs (specifically, qemu-kvm).

First of all, the guide explicitly states that you need to comment-out the `eth0` configuration on the host's `interfaces` file, yet you have `allow-hotplug eth0` in there. Comment that line out.

Secondly, when creating bridging setups involving physical interfaces like this, I like to add line(s) to the `interfaces` file to explicitly keep the physical interface(s) uninitialized. In this case, `eth0` is to be added to the bridge, so I would have this:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

And finally, it is a *little* weird to have different subnets on the same bridge. Although it *should* work, LXC is still under heavy development, so it's possible that even slightly unconventional network setups could expose bugs. Try putting your VM on the same subnet as the host (`46.105.102.0/24`), so that you don't need to explicitly muck with routes in your VM.